# Code sample for slartoolkit project

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Does anyone has the code to a full working example of slartoolkit (http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/) ?

Comment: What do you mean ? The CodePlex project has 2 samples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the [project site](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com) and the release notes carefully. You can find the source code for the SLARToolkit samples in the [repository](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets).

There's now also a [Beginner's Guide](http://slartoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Beginner's%20Guide&referringTitle=Documentation) available.